# If $\epsilon \in (0,1]$ and $\tan^2\theta \leq \epsilon$, then what are the admissible values of $\theta$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, asymptotics, convex-cone

> Let $\epsilon \in (0,1]$, and $\theta$ is such that $\tan^2\theta \leq \epsilon$. What are the admissible values of $\theta$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

The motivation for the question is the following:

> If a point $p$ makes an angle $\theta$ with x-axis, so that the above inequality holds, then it must be in a double cone with x-axis as its axis. I am trying to figure out its angular radius.

Comment: isn't the answer straight forward?

$$ n\pi -\arctan(\sqrt{\epsilon}) \le \theta \le n\pi +\arctan(\sqrt{\epsilon})  \qquad \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: yes, but is there any bound which does not involve arctan? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750254/if-frac-sin-alpha-sin-beta-le-1-epsilon-then-frac-alpha-beta-le

Comment: If you need a sharp bound, you are asking for $\arctan(\sqrt\epsilon).$ Would a slightly smaller (or slightly larger) quantity be acceptable? If not, the question is already answered.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^2\theta \leq \epsilon \iff -\sqrt {\epsilon}\le \tan \theta \leq \sqrt {\epsilon}$$

You have infinitely many solutions with the central one $$-\tan ^{-1}\sqrt {\epsilon}  \le \theta \le \tan ^{-1}\sqrt {\epsilon} $$

Other solutions are the shifts of this interval by multiples of $\pi$ in both directions.

Comment: This is correct, but I was looking for asymptotic growth here, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750254/if-frac-sin-alpha-sin-beta-le-1-epsilon-then-frac-alpha-beta-le. Assuming it is true , setting $\beta = \pi/2$, we get that $\alpha \leq (1+\sqrt{\epsilon})\pi/2$